# How can you use ballast-powered flouresecent lamp outputs to power LEDs?

Tags: led, uv, fluorescent-lamp, ballast, electronic-ballast

We have a 2G11-socket 36W germicidal UVC lamp in our air ducts ([Honeywell UC36W1006](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0721QG1JX)), and since [UV-C LEDs](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/720-SUCULBN2VCAGAM67) are readily available, I thought maybe I could make a PCB with a bunch of UV-C LEDs on it as a longer-lasting lower-power replacement.

[This study](https://www.lumistrips.com/lumistrips-blog/uv-fluence-for-disinfection-for-up-to-99-disinfection/) shows that a dose of 50mJ/cm2 will kill 90% of bacteria and viruses (1 log reduction), so very few LEDs would be required in the plenum (assuming a 30-second exposure).

I could just run DC to the new boards, but wondered if it would be feasible to use the existing twist-lock enclosures with a pin-compatible connection to the existing fluorescent driver outputs.  The PCB would plug directly into the blue socket below in place of the fluorescent lamp:

[image: UC36W1006]

I've looked around quite a bit, and while there are many places selling 2G11 bulb replacements, I can't find any technical documentation on the pinout.  Here's what I've found so far:

- It looks like 2G11 is also implemented as "[PL-L 4P](https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1gplYXQH0gK0jSZPiq6yvapXao/PL-L-2G11-Fluorescent-Tube-18W-24W-36W-40W-Energy-Saving-Lamp-CFL-4-Pins-Twin.jpg_.webp)" (Philips Linear Compact Fluorescent Lamps).
- [This video](https://youtu.be/ZM76IHfHf2s) shows lighting it with a ballast that has a 430V output.

There are 4 pins, two pairs to illuminate two elements.  The tube is a loop at the far end (not pictured) so (I think) the left and right elements would be the same as those at each end of a linear fluorescent tube:

[image: 2G11 bulb]

**Question:**

How can I use those 4 pins to get ~6V DC to illuminate UV-C LEDs?

Others have made [2G11 LED lamps](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QS53KR5) (but not UV), so clearly it can be done...but what components are involved in stepping down the lamp input to a DC level for LEDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you go further, consider the **cost** to replace the Hg-vapor lamp with LED's. The [data sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/588/ams_Osram_11_16_2022_SU_CULBN2_VC_EN-3076798.pdf) for LED in your link states output power is ~4 to 7 mW.  Specifications for a [similar 36W lamp](https://www.cureuv.com/products/philips-tuv-pll-36w-compatible-germicidal-uv-lamp) states its radiant output at 12 W, and this [Osram lamp](https://www.osram.com/ecat/PURITEC%20HNS%20UV-C-UV-C%20lamps%20for%20purification-Ultraviolet%20lamps-Industry-Specialty%20Lighting/com/en/GPS01_1028570/ZMP_86482/) claims 10.8 W. To get the same amount of UV-C radiation would require **1,500 to 3,000** LED's.

That said, there might be a similar lamp that fits that socket at **far less* than the OEM price.

As for [using the ballast](https://sound-au.com/lamps/fluoro-lamps.html) to get DC, that would not be practical. In the days of the [magnetic ballast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_ballast), some (newer) had three windings on the ballast transformer: two for filament power, which might be [12 VAC or so](https://www.giangrandi.org/electronics/fluorescenttubes/fluorescenttubes.shtml), and a third for ignition voltage, initially ~1,000 VAC, which drops to ~120 V on each arc (well, glow discharge) ignition. Others used a single resonant inductor/capacitor circuit to get those voltages. Your simple "adapter" would have to accommodate those voltage regimes.

However, an [electronic ballast](https://sound-au.com/lamps/fluoro-lamps.html#a4) is *far* more complex, with circuits to switch voltage to filaments and across the glow discharge. These voltages would be continually changing.

It would be simpler and *far* more efficient to tap into the AC mains **before** the ballast.

Comment: hmm, good point.  still, I'm curious how to tap into the outputs to get DC

Comment: @KJ7LNW, see edits.